Proxy inverso está mal de Jenkins
Mi contenedor que tiene Jenkins me dice este error:
WARNING h.d.ReverseProxySetupMonitor#getTestForReverseProxySetup: http://tti-jenkins.taotechideas.com/manage vs. https://tti-jenkins.taotechideas.com/manage/
la confiruacion del archivo nginx.conf de mi contenedor de nginx es la siguiente:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name tti-jenkins.taotechideas.com tti-sonarqube.taotechideas.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;  # Redirige HTTP a HTTPS
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name tti-jenkins.taotechideas.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/tti-jenkins.taotechideas.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/tti-jenkins.taotechideas.com/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://jenkins-blueocean:8080;  # Usar el nombre del contenedor
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name tti-sonarqube.taotechideas.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/tti-jenkins.taotechideas.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/tti-jenkins.taotechideas.com/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://frappe-sonarqube-1:9000;  # Usar el nombre del contenedor
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
    }
}


mi URL jenkins es:
https://tti-jenkins.taotechideas.com/
Que se vaya el error de:
Parece que la configuración de proxy inverso está mal
